# Change MYSQL_DATABASE etc. in docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am having some issues getting docker to create a completely new image with a new database.

I first started my containers, but had entered wrong credentials. I now want to build the image over with the right credentials.

This is my service

```
mysql:
        build: ./mysql
        image: custom-mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dsadjkasjd
            MYSQL_DATABASE: correct_db
            MYSQL_USER: correct_user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: correct_pass
        networks:
            main:
                aliases:
                    - database

        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I have tried removing all containers and images manually as well as

```
docker-compose down --rmi 'all'
docker-compose build --no-cache --pull
```

But not matter what I try it will only work with the passwords I used the first time around.

Is there some clever way of completely removing the container+image and building it again with a new database/users ?

Comment: you have to delete volume as well: docker volume rm volumename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script to generate the database from scratch (which evaluates the given environment variables) is only run on the first generation for the volume, as you can see in https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh.

You have two possibilites now: either stop the container, remove the volume, and restart the container; or start a bash in the running container, remove the data dir `/var/lib/mysql`, and restart the container

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the volume (or make its content empty) so on new startup it will generate the new database files with the new configuration.